# ajax for a array search

Tags: php, sql, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

my view code like this

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <=10; $i++):?>
        <tr>
            <td width="10">
                <?php echo $i;?>
            </td>

            <td>
            <input size="10" type="text" name="code[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" id="code" />
            </td>
            <td width="20%">
                <name="product[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" id="product"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input size="10"type="text" name="rate[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" id="rate" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input size="10" type="text" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" id="quantity" />
            </td>
            <td width="15%">
                <name="total[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" id="total"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input size="10" type="text" name="sell[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" id="sell" />
            </td>

        </tr>
        <?php endfor;?>
```

in the code field i will just type the code and in the product field ajax will set the corresponding product name.But the main problem is when type any code in seccond or third row it sets the product also for first row.can anyone fix this on array input of same name in ajax. i am in codigniter framework

Comment: please add your javascript to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same IDs for similar HTML tags in each row. This is a no-no; IDs are expected and assumed to be unique throughout the document.

Either replace your IDs with classes:

```
<td>
    <input size="10" type="text" name="code[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" class="code" />
</td>
```

or append the `$i` variable to each ID so that they are unique:

```
<td>
    <input size="10" type="text" name="code[]" value="<?php echo '';?>" id="code_<?php echo $i ?>" />
</td>
```

and adjust your JavaScript accordingly.